# Setting state using Object.assign is losing keys in the state

Tags: reactjs

Let me begin by saying I am a noob in React.

I fetch data in componentDidMount prepare/set my state. I have a remote API endpoint that spits out JSON data and it looks something like this.

```
  "popup": {
    "background": "bg",
    "url": "",
    "title": {
      "text": "title",
      "color": "#222",
      "bgColor": "#fff"
    },
    "button": {
      "text": "button",
      "color": "#222",
      "bgColor": "#567834"
    },
    "termsAndConditions": {
      "text": "termsAndConditions",
      "color": "#222",
      "bgColor": "#fff"
    }
  }
```

and based on this data I am rendering a stateless component that I am passing props to.

This is what my initial state looks like

```
this.state = {
  popup: {
    background: "",
    button: {
      color: "",
      bgColor: "",
      buttonRounded: false,
      text: "",
    },
    termsAndConditions: "",
    title: {
      bgColor: "",
      color: "",
      text: ""
    }
  }
}
```

And now is the time to update values of 'title' part from the form. So I am setting it's state like this

```
   handlePopupTitle(e) {
    this.setState({
      popup: {
        title: {
          text: e.target.value.trim()
        }
      }
    })
   }
```

However, soon I realized that React is going to override my current state and leave only

```
popup: {
  title: {
   text: "whatever my input value is"
  }
}
```

So, I used Object.assign to create a new object and use that to set a state since mutating your state is obviously a big NO.

Now my event handler looks like this

```
handlePopupTitle(e) {

  const newState = Object.assign( {}, this.state.popup, {
    title: {
      text: e.target.value
    }
  })

  this.setState({
    popup: newState
  })

}
```

But now the problem is I am only updating 'text' key in 'title' object and all the other keys such as 'color', 'bgColor'are lost since I am only setting 'text'.

I tried putting Object.assign inside another Object.assign but it just doesn't seem like an ideal solution to me. And one more thing to note that I can't change the nested structure of my state because the structure of my data is not going to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler and much easier solution will be to make use of `immutability-helper` npm package.

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

.....


var newState = update(state, {
  popup: {
    title: {
      text: {
        $set: e.target.value;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Have a look at **[this doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)** for more info

Comment: I used that too but then I I see an uncaught error in the console saying

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text, color, bgColor}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons"

And I didn't know what it meant so I assumed I did something wrong so I reverted my code

Comment: Shubham, and I am sure this error something to do with the way I am rendering my state in my stateless component. Had my state been like an array, this wouldn't happen but I have no choice.

Comment: However, you have answered my question so I will accept that as the best answer. Thanks man

Comment: So you mean your problem is solved or there is another error

Comment: There is another error but that has to do with the structure of my state. It is one nested object. Hence I am getting 

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text, color, bgColor}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons

Comment: Oh okay, no problem , I am sure you will figure it out